# NullPointerException while using JSON datatype with Jooq

Tags: jooq

I am using jooq 3.15.12 and I am getting the following error while generating code:

```
    Error while generating table ArmourDb.REGEX
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError(AbstractDatabase.java:3104)
        at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getRelations(AbstractDatabase.java:2317)
        at org.jooq.meta.DefaultColumnDefinition.getPrimaryKey(DefaultColumnDefinition.java:100)
        at org.jooq.meta.AbstractTableDefinition.getPrimaryKey(AbstractTableDefinition.java:91)
        at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateTable(JavaGenerator.java:5019)
        at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateTables(JavaGenerator.java:5000)
        at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:582)
        at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:537)
        at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:436)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:879)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:233)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:228)
        at com.linkedin.gradle.mysql.tasks.MySQLJooqCodegenTask.taskAction(MySQLJooqCodegenTask.java:32)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

The table looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE REGEX (
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   WORD VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1000),
   TRAITS JSON,
   MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   MODIFIED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I have observed that JSON field is causing this issue, if I change the datatype from json to some other type then the java files get generated without any issue.
As per the stack trace, NullPointerException is coming while getting relations of the table.

Comment: I cannot reproduce such a problem with the latest version of jOOQ. Can you please try to upgrade? If the issue persists, what's your code generation configuration?